# How to make my CPP console app installable/redistributable which depends on some external files?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-installer, console-application, software-distribution

*I am new to this coding world. So forgive me if any dumb question is asked or I made any mistakes*

I am making a cpp tool which works well on my machine & also on others too. But inside it there is a function which works with some **BAT & VBS** files stored in a separate folder. Now the problem is when I am sharing the **EXE** file it is not working as the folder directory can not be found on other devices.

Now how can i solve this scenario? Is there a way to make installer for the console app which will copy the necessary files and folders in to the user's **C** drive? Or can I include the files into the **EXE** and extract them to a folder so the the program can use those?

Is there any possible solution for this ?

*I am using Visual Studio Code & mingw gcc compiler for building the app*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating installer using setup creator(https://installforge.net). You can package multiple files in the installer and select installation directory to something like c:/program files/your_application_name.
That way your executable and other files will be in the same folder and it will also create a start menu shortcut

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. Let me try it right now

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward solution I can think of is to include the dependency files with the exe when you share it to others.

Another way is to embed the dependency files as resource files into your executable when you build it in Visual Studio, then extract them when you run the exe (A little difficult to implement)

Or just create an installer like [this](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html)

Comment: But I am using Visual Studio Code. Is there any other way other than using Visual Studio IDE ?

Comment: easiest way is to put the exe file and its dependency binaries in the same folder

Comment: I know that but that is not a good way of distributing the tool I guess. :-)